# Disable Outbound Web Requests

Tags: performance, multisite, feed

I've setup  wordpress on AWS. I want to reduce as much network traffic as possible. What services/jobs do I need to disable in Wordpress?

Answer (score 8):

Defining `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL` constant (`wp-config.php` is good place to do this) would kill all outgoing network requests, other than those for hostnames, defined in `WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS`.

See [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/class-http.php#L535) for details, doesn't seem to be documented in Codex.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see all network traffic from your site check out the Core Control plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/
You can also use this to permit or shut down different requests and cron jobs.

Note, by defining WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL in your wp-config.php this blocks all external requests. If you want to enable WordPress update checks you will need to include api.wordpress.org in WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS.